Behaviour of num_threads(0) in openMP
So I am basically working on a program with many for loops, which I am parallelizing with OpenMP.
I am using #pragma omp parallel for for parallelization of the for(){} loop.
As some may know there is an option to set the number of threads for the for-loop, which is via:
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(the_number_of_threads_you_want)

But when I set the_number_of_threads_you_want to 0, then I notice a quick program with parallelization and without any error. In fact it performs better than a fixed initialization of say the_number_of_threads_you_want to 2, 5, or 20.
Can I know what OpenMP does when I input num_threads(0) to the pragma?
My guess is that setting num_threads(0) would instruct OpenMP to fork the optimal number of threads required for the task, optimizing between overhead and speedup, similar to passing in OMP_NUM_THREADS. Can I know if this is the case?
I tried searching through the OpenMP documentation and resources online but could not get any info.
EDIT:
I forgot to mention it in the beginning but just passing 0 into num_threads() is giving an error, but storing zero in an int variable and then passing THAT into num_threads() is not giving an error.
For example:
int number_of_threads = 0;
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(number_of_threads)
for(){
}

How can this behaviour be explained?
Background info:
The performance with num_threads(0) is consistent with for loops of different lengths i.e.
// always getting a good speedup (compared to using constant number 
// of threads like 2, 4, or 20) when N = 100, 500 or 1000
int number_of_threads = 0;
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(number_of_threads)
for(i=0; i<N; i++){ 
// some work
}


The docs state:

The num_threads expression must evaluate to a positive integer value

Since that condition is not met, it would be invalid (or UB)
Note that MSVC rejects the code with the following error:

error C3026: 'num_threads': constant expression must be positive instead of '0'

G++ accepts the code with the warning:

warning: 'num_threads' value must be positive [-Wopenmp]

And Clang++ rejects it:

error: argument to 'num_threads' clause must be a strictly positive integer value

What you can do, is put in a omp_get_num_threads() inside the parallel for to see how many are actually running; however, I'd emphasize that what you currently have is not valid.

Since you updated your question to use a variable instead of a constant, the behaviour cannot be explained, as undefined behaviour is inherently undefined. That said, a quick test shows all three compilers taking it to mean the same as setting to max; but since it's UB, you cannot rely on this.

though once you are in UB land nothing is certain. omp_get_num_threads() could then in principle return a number that does not correspond to the actual number of threads. I'd try it nevertheless

Thanks Chris.
But I forgot to mention it in the beginning but just passing 0 into num_threads() is giving an error, but storing zero in an int variable and then passing THAT into num_threads() is not giving an error & gives the kind of behaviour I mentioned in the post & what led me to ask the question.
For example:
int number_of_threads = 0;
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(number_of_threads)
How can this behaviour be explained?

@PhotonicSauce, then it cannot be explained, as undefined behaviour is inherently undefined. That said, a quick test shows all three compiler taking it to mean the same as setting to max; but since it's UB, you cannot rely on that.

@PhotonicSauce the compiler could provde that int x; #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(x) is the same as #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(0) but it does not have to. The absence of the warning / error is just a matter of convenience, but the problem in the code is the same

Note that mathematically speaking, "a positive integer value" can be zero. I agree that zero thread does not make sense, but then why the OpenMP specification doesn't say instead "a strictly positive integer value"?

The OpenMP specification uses the, to our knowledge, usual definition of "positive integer number" that excludes 0 because in that definition 0 is neither negative nor positive.
